# Including js file in react based app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am beginner to `react`....
I am trying to convert a **website** into `react` by breaking it into **components**.

My question how can I include my js files..

Will the code work if I include the js file in index.html or do I have to separate `js` code for each components ?
Some of the `js` code are required for each **components.**

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want?

Comment: I have a js file  which is to be in each component....so what i am doing is I am including in index.html as <script src="myfilename.js"></script>                                     but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: So instead of including it in `<script>` tag why don't you import it in all your files by using `import` statement just like I did in my answer.

Comment: Actually I got the answer it's working if i put the js file as script tag in index.html..there was some other error I was doing....but we cannot import the js file the way we import components......the js file i was including was not written in react.......

Comment: Oh so it wasn't a react component, can you edit your question and include that js file so that we can see it what it was

Answer (score 0):

You could just put the JavaScript code in the component which uses it. If you have a slider, you can put the JS functions, which control said slider in a `<slider/>` component.

Read [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `create-react-app`, this will create a demo project of React.
You can either write the component code in one file which will be `App.js` or if you want then you can create different files of every component. `index.js` will be the entry JS file, so the `ReactDOM.render` will take place in that file.

```
//App.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FirstComp from './FirstComp';
class App extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {/* JSX Statements */}
                <FirstComp />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;

//FirstComp.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class FirstComp extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {/* JSX Statements */}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default FirstComp;
```

Try [FullStack React](https://www.fullstackreact.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as something from './something.js';
```

Now that you have imported the something.js file,  you can call any function in something.js file.

```
something.someFunction()
```